# Characterization of biholomorphic maps from : $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis

It's a consequence of Casorati-Weierstrass theorem that any injective analytic function can't have a essential singularity. Moreover since $f'(z)\neq 0$ $\forall z \in$ $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ it can only have simple poles.

So biholomorphic functions should be something like: $f(z)=\frac{A}{z}+Bz+C$ but this functions can have $z_1\neq 0$ such that $f(z_1)=0$  so there are two options:

- $f(z)=\frac{A}{z}$
- $f(z)=Az$

Is this alright?

Comment: To me $f'$ nonvanishing implies simple zeros, how do you get it to imply simple poles? Also how come your expression for $f$ doesn't have any higher powers of $z$? Certainly $\exp(z)$ is injective analytic but it's not of either form you give, and it has higher powers of $z$ in its Laurent expansion.

Comment: @anon If f is injective then $\frac{1}{f}$ is injective and it has a zero with the same order as the pole of $f$.  Moreover if $f$ is holomorphic then $f(1/z)$ has either a essential singularity or a pole at 0 so $f$ can't have higher powers of $z$. And exponential function is not injective $e^{4\pi i}=e^{2\pi i}$

Comment: Righto. Sorry for the derp.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a pretty good argument.

Comment: "Moreover since f′(z)≠0 ∀z∈ ℂ∖{0} it can only have simple poles." I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: If we have an injective analytic function $f(z)$ then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is also injective. Assuming $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$ then, $f(z)$ would look something like this: $\frac{1}{f(z)}=(z-z_0)^n g(z)$ with $g(z)$ also injective. But injective analytic functions have non-vanishing derivative and n=1.